# ROS2 galactic - failed in running demo in RHEL

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS2 galactic in RHEL 8.5 using installation using RPM method found here:
https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/RHEL-Install-RPMs.html

When trying the example [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/RHEL-Install-RPMs.html#try-some-examples), the listener is not printing any messages.
'ros2 topic list' and 'ros2 doctor' doesn't return to command prompt.

any idea how to troubleshoot this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400440/ros2-galactic---failed-in-running-demo-in-rhel/) by [cwrx777](https://answers.ros.org/users/104579/cwrx777/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is resolved after setting the firewall configuration to allow udp.

---

Originally posted by [cwrx777](https://answers.ros.org/users/104579/cwrx777/) with karma: 16 on 2022-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0